# Excel VBA Lookup

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Trying to use VBA in Excel to perform some VLookup equivalent function.  I have this sample table:

[image]

Basically, this is what I want to do:

1) Based on the value in B12, lookup the value in table A1:A8.
2) Set cell B13 with the lookup returned value
3) If no match found (example, B12=100000), throw an error message.

I am currently using a bunch of "IF.. ElseIf" statements and it is becoming too cumbersome to maintain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your qtys are in ascending order. what's wrong with vlookup?

Comment: I would use a formula here, especially if it's such simple logic, as opposed to writing VBA adding complexity to the workbook where none is needed.

Comment: @Jeeped - For certain reason, I don't want to use a vlookup formula in B13.  Instead, I rather use a VBA that does the lookup and set the value B13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the worksheet's private code sheet (right-click worksheet name tab, View Code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "B12" Then
        On Error GoTo meh
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim m As Variant
        If IsNumeric(Target) Then
            If Target < 1 Or Target > Application.Max(Range("A2:A8")) Then
                Target.Offset(1, 0) = "out of range"
            Else
                m = Application.Match(Target, Range("A1:A8"))
                Target.Offset(1, 0) = Cells(m, "B").Value
            End If
        End If
    End If

meh:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code and it works.  I will have to tweak a bit more but that essentially is the core.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just use formula at Cell B13:

```
=IF(B10>A8,"Error",INDEX($A$2:$B$8, SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A8<=B10)),2))
```

That's for inclusive (i.e. Qty 1-9 belongs to level 1) based on the example you given.

Comment: I get that.  What if I want the the result to be placed at a different cell... Example. C13?  Basically, setting the result at another location.  There is no function I know of in excel that allows me to do that.  That is why I am looking at VBA.